# Get groups with flex?

Tags: flex-lexer

Heres an example rule for oct values. Instead of using YYTEXT i'd like to get the value, letter and the # at end (8,...64). How might i get them? I guessed printf("%s", $1) to see if i'd get the value but lex gave me a compile error instead

```
0([0-7]+)(([us])(8|16|32|64))?
```

Also it appears "group" isn't in the [manual](http://westes.github.io/flex/manual/).

Comment: I don't think you can use capturing groups in flex, see http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3901835/how-do-i-use-regular-expression-capturing-groups-with-jflex/5088605#5088605.

Answer (score 8):

There are no capturing groups in flex.

I think this would best be represented as several states, with separate matching rules and state transitions.